# How to create a loop inside wp_query wordpress function?

Tags: arrays, loops, wordpress

I want print array in a loop and want to put it inside wp_query. Is it Possible?
If there are other alternatives kindly mention it.

```
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Subscriber', 'fields' => 'all',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    // Here I want to create a loop
    // loop will start from here repeating the array
    array(
    'key'       => 'user_group_name',
    'value'     => 'Panera Group 2 Encino',
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    // loop end
    /*array(
    'key'       => 'user_group_name',
    'value'     => 'West Hollywood',
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),*/
)));
```